# Calling rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is example code:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2005-01-01', periods=4)
A = [1,2,2,3]
B = [2,3,4,5]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'B':B},index = dates)
df1.loc['2005-01-04'].tolist()
```

It works just fine
Is there a way for me to give an integer 2 with a row index so it would give me a the row `2005-01-02`
I have a 1000 row dataframe that I got with a for loop, and when I try to call a row in the same fashion it gives me an error saying that

> label[] is not in the [index]

And that's the main problem that I can't figure out.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Writing the piece of code you tried and showing the expected result would already help you to find useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.ix` to select the range of the DataFrame you are interested in.

By label:

```
df1.ix['2005-01-03':'2005-01-04']
```

By index number:

```
df1.ix[2:4]
```

**Update based on comments**

You can work out the integer index of the date using `get_loc`.

```
i = df1.index.get_loc('2005-01-04')
offset = 2
df1.ix[i-offset: i]
```

Comment: That works, but can I give just one date, and then specify how many dates before that I am interested in?

Comment: And for whatever reason I get the same error with my actual datatframe.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. 
But I still can't figure out why the same approach doesn't work with my actual dataframe

Comment: What is the datatype of your index? Are you certain that date is actually in the index?

Comment: Originally dates were in a list, And information on A,B,C is also in a list. I introduced series using dates as index. make dataframe with that series.

i have no problem with `df.iloc[]` but `df.loc[]` gives an error.

Comment: That must mean that the date you are looking for is not in the index or the index is not recognising the format of the label you are providing. If you print `df.index` what does it show? Could there be a date format issue?

Comment: `Index[(2005-01-01, 2005-01-02, etc],
dtype ='object')`
Is there a way to change type?

Comment: Now do the same with your example df1 and look at the difference.

Comment: Just did, I see the difference, thank you. Is there a way to change type? Or maybe an simpler way would be to specify type when I am calling a row with `df.loc[]`

Comment: Actually it is easy to do. `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Thanks again for helping to figure out my error!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.